# Setup project in VS2013 does not have C++ 2005 redistrbutable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

[image]
I have created setup project in VS2013 in the prerequisite section i have all the component related to 4.5 framework (lowest is 3.5 framework). One of my component needs **C++ 2005 redistrbutable** is there any way by which i can add it in  prerequisite section

Comment: What do u mean by _add in Preequisite section_

Comment: My prerequisite  does not show C++ 2005 redistrbutable as it shows visual c++ 2013 redistrbutables. As shown in screen shot

Comment: Try to install the C++ 2005 manually , here is the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5638)

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add the merge module from the windows sdk on the development machine.

Path would be C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules

Also you can deploy the couple of dlls of VC redist manually in your own installer (in local directory), please see link below.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291(VS.80).aspx

Side by side assemblies location.
C:\Windows\winsxs

Comment: Ya tried adding Merge Modules(.msm) but the list does not have C++ 2005 in it

Comment: Is there a chance that you may not have VC 2005 msm installed (should come with VS 2005 setup) on the PC? If not then you can try to manually deploy the dlls, that is a good option as well.

Comment: Yes i don't have VS2005 in my system, should i install that or i can just copy from the system where VS2005 is installed.

Comment: You can copy the msm from any system where VS 2005 is installed... you may need to check on x86 and 64 bit versions